# CSS Transform not working with tall content

Tags: css, viewport, css-transforms

When using transform to vertically center content, it works fine if the content is not taller than the view port, but if it is taller, you cannot scroll to see the very top. Is there a fix?

[See example of content being pushed off screen.](https://jsbin.com/fevume/edit?html,css,output)

CSS

```
.center {
    position: $position;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
p{
  height: 1500px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="center">
  <h1>I am pushed off screen!?</h1>
  <p>Tall Content...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to scroll ok in the example on http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ what is he doing differently?

Comment: can you tell me for what you are using transform: translateY(-50%); for class center ???

Comment: I use translateY(-50%); to vertically center content. See http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: Did you add the proper vendor prefixes as stated on zerosixthree.se ( -ms-transform and -webkit-transform )

Comment: Your container elements (in this case `html` and `body`) don't have absolute heights set, so `top: 50%;` isn't going to do anything. See the demo code stripped down to what you have, and it creates the same problem: http://codepen.io/TylerH/pen/GZNKGK (here, the container `.block-of-text` is missing `height: 220px;`

Comment: @TylerH Do you know of a way to keep the height dynamic and not cut off the top?

Comment: @Justin Not off the top of my head. It seems that browsers don't extend scrollbars for elements that are positioned off-screen via negative amounts (e.g. translateX or translateY with -50%). I'm not sure if this is because of the negative translation value or if it is because of the top or left edges of the document screen having weird properties.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29339833#29339833 Related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the CSS Transform Rendering Model (From W3C Spec):

> Specifying a value other than `none` for the `transform` property
>   establishes a new **local coordinate system** at the element that it is
>   applied to. The mapping from where the element would have rendered
>   into that local coordinate system is given by the element’s
>   transformation matrix. Transformations are cumulative. That is,
>   elements establish their local coordinate system within the coordinate
>   system of their parent. From the perspective of the user, an element
>   effectively accumulates all the transform properties of its ancestors
>   as well as any local transform applied to it. The accumulation of
>   these transforms defines a current transformation matrix (CTM) for the
>   element.

Further reading: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering

---

Let's start from the basics, this is the default behaviour for a child inside parent:

```css
.parent {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px dashed #666;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<p>Container: 200 x 200 px</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h4>100 x 100</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if we want to use a `top` offset, we need to use positioning.

```css
.parent {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px dashed #666;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Container: 200 x 200 px</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h4>100 x 100</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

At this point, you want to vertically align the child by adding `transform: translateY(-50%);` but before we do that, let's see what happens if `parent` has no defined `height`, I.E. the height is dynamic based on child:

```css
.parent {
  width:200px;
  border: 1px dashed #666;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Container: 200 x AUTO px</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h4>100 x 100</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `top` offset is pretty much ignored because the browser cannot calculate a percentage of `auto` height. Therefore, when you try to add the `transform: translateY` property, the element will go outside the bounds of the parent:

```css
.parent {
  width:200px;
  border: 1px dashed #666;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<p>Container: 200 x AUTO px</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h4>100 x 100</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

To conclude, `transform` properties cannot work properly because the `position` offset cannot be calculated when it's in percentages while the parent has `auto` / dynamic height. If you use fixed height, it should work as expected:

```css
.parent {
  width:200px;
  border: 1px dashed #666;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  top:50px; /* half of 100px is 50px - instead of 50% */
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<p>Container: 200 x AUTO px</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h4>100 x 100</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

But of course, that is not dynamic. You could use JavaScript to get/update the fixed pixel dimensions.

As explained by the W3C Spec, since transformed elements create a coordination relative to the element itself, scrollbars will not be created if the element overflows the viewport or its parent, see example:

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px dashed #666;
  position: fixed;
}

div.red {
  background:red;
  transform:translate(-50px, -50px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

---

If you want to keep it you'd have to use JavaScript to run calculations for dynamic height, otherwise, you could vertically align items using the `vertical-align: middle` property with a parent set as `table-cell` that is a child of `display: table`. So for example, if you knew the exact top value, it would work:

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px dashed #666;
  position: relative;
  top:50px;
  float:left;
}

.center {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
}

.transform .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* table wrapper */

.wrapper.table {
  float:right;
  display: table;
}

.table .center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper transform">
  <div class="center">
    <h4>I am pushed off screen!?</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper table">
  <div class="center">
    <h4>I'm smarter.</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit: Flexbox Solution**

In addition to the old school table solution, you could use a modern approach: Flexbox.

```css
.flexbox {
  border:1px dashed #666;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal centering */
  align-items: center; /* vertical centering */
  flex-direction: column; /* makes sure children are under each other */
  min-height:200px;
}

.flexbox * {
  border:1px solid red;
}

.flexbox p {
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    <h4>Flexbox Magic</h4>
    <p>The center of attention!</p>
</div>
```

The flex container expands based on its children, so it's a really neat dynamic solution.

Flexbox Support: [Can I Use: Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Comment: "That's just how the transform effect works" Not that I don't believe you... but could you share a source (maybe from the spec) specifying whether the browser should add scrolling when elements are moved outside of the viewport via negative translate values?

Comment: Thank you @Aziz that all makes sense. Do you know if Flexbox would suffer from the same limitations as transform?

Comment: @Justin, actually Flexbox would be a valid solution too and the only drawback is browser support. I'll include it in my answer, I'm just a bit old-school, I guess :)

Comment: Great, I just tried Flexbox and it worked. I appreciate the simplicity of `table-cell` answer but would rather lean towards the future (IE<10 users be damned). Flexbox also doesn't need an extra wrapper div.